# Bash script reading line for '+', if not present, change line

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am writing a bash script and trying to change lines in my file. I currently have:

```
 if [[ ! $line == *[+]* ]]
   then
     [command to change line]
```

I merely want to change the line by adding on to the text already there. Any suggestions? I have tried:

```
sed -i 'Ns/.*/replacement-line/' file.txt
```

and

```
sed -i '/Text_to_be_replaced/c\This is the new line.' file.txt
```

among some others found online to no avail.

My full script is:

```
#!bin/bash
filename="227.dat"
while ((i++)); read -r line; do
sed -i 's/(/  /g' $filename
sed -i 's/)//g' $filename
sed -i 's/,/    /g' $filename
sed -i 's/-x/-1     0     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/x/ 1     0     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/-y/ 0    -1     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/y/ 0     1     0/g' $filename
sed -i 's/-z/ 0     0    -1/g' $filename
sed -i 's/z/ 0     0     1/g' $filename
[*command to add to line*]
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: How are you setting `$line`?

Comment: while ((i++)); read -r line; do

Comment: So you're reading the line from the terminal, and if the user doesn't type something with `+` you want to change the file?

Comment: it is reading the line from a text file

Comment: Please post a MCVE that demonstrates what you're trying to do. I shouldn't have to ask for each little thing like this.

Comment: What is a MCVE? I'm sorry I'm very new to all of this

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is highly inefficient, first you don't need a loop `sed` will apply the transformation to all lines, second you don't need to run multiple times, `sed` can run multiple scripts at once.  Also some transformation rules can be combined, for example `sed -E 's/(-)?z/0 0 \11/'` can replace the last two.

Comment: You are running `sed -i` in a loop over a file, that is currently being read by the shell as a part of while loop. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the test in the `sed` command:

```
sed -i '/+/! s/.*/replacement-line/' file.txt
```

The `!` means to do the replacement only on lines that don't match the regular expression.

Comment: receive error `sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: Are you using a variable in the replacement? Does the value of that variable contain a `/` character?

Comment: You either need to escape the `/`, or use a character that won't be in the variable as the `s` delimiters.

Comment: It shouldn't literally be `[+]`, just `+`. The brackets in the Bash comparison in the question are for a character class (even though they have no effect).

Comment: @BenjaminW. ofc, momentarily forgot that globs use brackets too.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, this worked with a space between ! and s